# Installing ROS Jade with Gazebo 5.0.1

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

While following the tutorial for installing Gazebo with ROS, I reach a point where there is no option for ROS Jade. The current text looks like:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control
```

However when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-jade-gazebo-ros-control
```

it appears that the latter package ros-jade-gazebo-ros-control isn't available. Can I / how can I proceed installing ROS J with Gazebo 5.0.1?

For slightly more information I've installed Gazebo 5.0.1, and tested to know it works. I've installed ROS Jade via ros-jade-desktop-full , and I've done some limited testing to see that it works. All this is on Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8802/installing-ros-jade-with-gazebo-5.0.1/) by [ImBunting](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/869/imbunting/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bahom](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2420/bahom/) on 2016-01-26**:
Hy, I am exactly having the same problem and I didn't find any solution to that. Could you tel me how did you proceed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

gazebo-ros-control has not been released as a package for Jade at this moment. [Full information about the reasons](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/179) is available in the issue tracker.

You will probably need to compile it from source at this moment. I'm going to update the documentation, thanks for reporting.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0